# Move attribute and remove tag in XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath-2.0

I'm quite new in xml for sql and very confused about how to solve this issue.

I have the following XML, wich corresponds to a colunm called @XmlContent in my table tbAgreement (composed by @ID, @Code, @Name and @XmlContent):

```
<agreement>
   <vendor code='VND_johnmcfly>
   <city code='CTY_Vegas'>
   <events>
     <event date='2012-21-08'/>
     <event date='2013-20-01'/>
     <event date='2014-20-01'/>
   </events>
</agreement>
```

What I want to do is to move the code value from vendor and city tags and put it as events attributes:

```
<agreement>
   <events>
     <event date='2012-21-08' vendor='VND_johnmcfly' city='CTY_Vegas'/>
     <event date='2013-20-01' vendor='VND_johnmcfly' city='CTY_Vegas'/>
     <event date='2014-20-01' vendor='VND_johnmcfly' city='CTY_Vegas'/>
   </events>
</agreement>
```

It is important to say that the old tags vendor and city should be removed and all table records respectively updated. What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have already find the answer, but it might be helpful for someone else

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml=
'<agreement>
   <vendor code="VND_johnmcfly" />
   <city code="CTY_Vegas" />
   <events>
     <event date="2012-21-08"/>
     <event date="2013-20-01"/>
     <event date="2014-20-01"/>
   </events>
</agreement>'

declare @txml table(x xml)
insert into @txml values(@xml);

UPDATE t SET x=x.query('<agreement>
<events>
{
for $d in //events/event/@date,
    $v in //vendor/@code,
    $c in //city/@code
return <event date="{$d}" city="{$c}" vendor="{$v}"/>
}
</events>
</agreement>')
FROM @txml t 

select * from @txml
```